# MySQL SELECT INNER JOIN mistaken

Tags: mysql, join

I am trying to retrieve the 'Roles' sets of a given users.id on a query with INNER JOIN combined with a WHERE condition. But things go wrong.

My database has four tables:

```
t_users : id, username, userpass, status, ...
t_action: id, id_user, id_role, id_type_role, ...
t_role: id, libelle, status
t_type_role: id, libelle, status
```

My query:

```sql
SELECT U.id AS ID, R.libelle AS ROLE, T.libelle AS TYPE
FROM t_user U
JOIN t_action A ON A.id_user = U.id
JOIN t_type_role T ON T.id = A.id_type_role
JOIN t_role R ON R.id = A.id_role
WHERE A.id_user = '1' AND R.libelle = 'System'
```

But this query returns no data. (Tested on a phpmyadmin SQL board.)

Comment: If the query output is empty then there is no data which mathes all conditions.

Comment: Check that you use correct collation for `R.libelle = 'Système'` condition.

Comment: There is no published table called role and if this is a typo and should be.t_role there is no column with a value system

Comment: [mre] [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
SELECT u.id AS id,
       r.libelle AS role,
       t.libelle AS type
FROM users u
JOIN action a ON a.id_user = u.id
JOIN type_role t ON t.id = a.id_type_role
JOIN role r ON r.id = a.id_role
WHERE a.id_user =1 
AND t.libelle = 'System';
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=20570938deb2bec281d5070dd28bf19d

Don't put single quotes on integers, change `WHERE a.id_user ='1'` to  `WHERE a.id_user = 1`.

`libelle = 'System'` is in the `type_role` table not in the `role` table

Comment: great ! it works now. sorry for the delay. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

as Akina has already mentioned in the comment section, there is no "libelle" value in the table "role" which equals 'Système' as you has mentioned it above. That is the reason why you do not get any output. Fix it to 'System' in the MySQL database and try it out again.